# Побитная обработка данных в php

Tags: php

Имеем буфер из n байт (получается строковый массив).

Имеем переменную BitsPerComponent=[1;maxBits]

Нужно сформировать массив, который будет содержать элементы, колиество битов в которых равно bits и заполненных последовательно из буфера.

Пример:

```
$buffer="1234567890";
$bits=8;
Должны получить что то типа
$result=array(ord('1'),...,ord('7'),ord('8'),ord('9'),ord('0'));
```

Чтобы не выглядеть криведкой: bits=8 - классический случай, когда читаем по символьно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Читаем, кажется, в любом случае посимвольно. Не наблюдал у php возможностей для работы с битами.

Вот такое накидал. Считаем, что байты записаны в big-endian

```
<?
$string = '1234567890';
$components = array();
$bytes = unpack('c*', $string);
$bits = 16;
$n = $tmp = 0;
foreach ($bytes as $byte)
  for ($i = 7; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    $n++;
    $tmp = $tmp*2 + (int)(!!($byte & (1<<$i)));
    if ($n%$bits == 0) {
      $components[] = $tmp;
      $tmp = 0;
    }
  }
if ($n % $bits != 0)
  $components[$tmp];
var_dump($components);
?>
```

Во всяком случае, при `$bits == 8` `$components` получилось эквивалентно `$bytes`.

Comment: Как можно оптимизировать? У меня таких символов до 2х мегабайт. И на каждый будет по куче вложенных циклов.

Comment: Лучше всего отказаться от пхп в пользу чего-то компилируемого и обрабатывать не массив int32, а участок памяти (т.е. именно байты). Хотя суть цикла останется та же, ибо байт - минимальная единица для адресации.

Comment: > Лучше всего отказаться от пхп в пользу чего-то ...

Что-то часто в последнее время эта фраза встречается :D

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov ну ее по-моему логично писать везде, где на php пытаются работать с битовыми масками, графикой, драйверами и подобным)

Comment: > ну ее по-моему логично писать везде

Дальше можно было не продолжать фразу :)

Comment: Согласен с Вами полностью (лучше компилируемый язык). Я написал парсер pdf (коих много в инете, но только через опу сделанных - в частности мне нужно было вытаскивать текст с координатами и фоновые картинки). Картинки имеют параметр BitsPerComponent - который разный для разных картинок. Комбинированный метод (текст парсим средствами php, картинки утилитами) не подошел по ряду причин: хостер не дает запускать утилиты, а заказчик не покупает впс. Ну и хотелось чтобы все доставалось в одной коробке (допишу картинки - выложу в опенсорс под IraPdfReader).

Comment: Кстати, оень разочарован исходниками pdftohtml для парсинга pdf и классом fpdf для сборки документов (переписал его под личные нужды для позиционирования текста с учетом характеристик шрифта ascent, иначе он позиционирует от baseline текста). Ну и за основу взял xpdf - правда только для картинок.

Comment: Ну и проблема отсюда пошла:specified—for example, one component for DeviceGray, three for DeviceRGB, four for DeviceCMYK, or whatever number is required by a particular DeviceN space. Each component is a 1-, 2-, 4-, 8-, or (PDF 1.5) 16-bit integer, permitting the representation of 2, 4, 16, 256, or (PDF 1.5) 65536 distinct values for each component.

Answer (score 3):

Не уверен на счет производительности gmp'а, но вот читабельность точно получше будет :)

```
$string = '1234567890';
$bits   = 16;

$hex   = bin2hex($string);
$bin   = gmp_init($hex, 16);
$shift = gmp_pow(2, $bits);
$mask  = gmp_sub($shift, 1);
$len   = strlen($hex) * 4;

$result = array();
do {
    $result[] = gmp_intval(gmp_and($bin, $mask));
    $bin      = gmp_div($bin, $shift);

} while ( ($len -= $bits) > 0);
```

Comment: Эээм

    bin2hex($string); // o_O что будет в hex? false?

И как быть с, например, 215-ю битами в маске?)

Comment: В $hex будет hex-представление бинарных данных.

> 215-ю битами в маске?

В таком случае просто заменить `gmp_intval()` на `gmp_strval()` и все будет работать для любого количества бит. А вот как вы решите проблему с `$bits > 64` в своем коде? :)

Comment: Пардон. Я думал, bin2hex делает что-то вроде "'1010' => 'A'". Про >64 - аргумент, да) Опять же привет php.

Comment: На деле максимум вроде 64 бита и будет.